# The Maharsha's Funeral Procession

Tags: sources-mekorot, funeral-burial-levaya, story-identification, maharsha

I heard a tale about a wonder that happened during the [Maharsha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharsha)'s funeral procession which involved a church falling down and the Maharsha sitting up in his bier.

What is the original source of this story?

Comment: https://www.lookstein.org/blog/is-the-menorah-still-in-rome-and-does-it-matter/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw the story in Otzros Maharsha, who quoted it from [Kochvei Or](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D).

I haven't searched further, but I assume that if this is the first source the biographers of the Maharsha found, it won't be too easy to find an earlier source.

> באוסטרה מקום המרש"א ז"ל היה טומאה להגויים, כשהיו היהודים צריכים לילך
> עם נפטר דרך המקום הזה (כי לא היה להם דרך אחרת) אז היו מצלצלים וכו',
> וכל מי שהלך דרך שם המיר דתו רחמנא לצלן. וצוה המרש"א ז"ל, שכאשר יהיה
> נפטר מהעולם וישאו דרך שם, יניחו עליו חבור המהרש"א שעשה. ועשו כן. ושם
> התאספו כל הכומרים והתחילו לצלצל. והעמידו את מיטתו, ויושב המהרש"א ז"ל
> את עצמו והתחיל לדפדף את הדפים, והתחילה הטומאה עם האנשים להיבלע בארץ,
> ונבלעו כולם בארץ. ועד היום יש סימן מזה שנבלעה בארץ.
>
> In Ostroh [Ukraine], the area of the Maharsha, there was a church
> [lit. impurity] for the non-Jews. When the Jews had to pass by this
> church during a funeral (because there was no other path to get to the
> cemetery) the church would start ringing its bells etc. and whoever
> was walking past would renounce his religion [i.e. was compelled to
> acknowledge Christianity in some way], Heaven-forfend. The Maharsha
> dictated in his will that when he passes on from this world, [and]
> they will pass [his body] by this church they [i.e. the Jews] should
> rest upon him his Torah writings. And so they [the Jews] did. [As the
> funeral procession passed by the church] the priests gathered and
> began to ring the bells. The [body of the] Maharsha arose from repose
> and sat himself up and began to leaf through the pages [of his Torah
> writings], and the church and its people began to get swallowed by the
> earth, and they were entirely swallowed up by the earth. And until
> this day, there is an indication [i.e. landmark] where the earth
> swallowed them up.

Comment: It seems that the picture is cutoff at the left side

Comment: That's how it is on Otzar Hachochma